# Calculating the position of an object on a parabola

Tags: geometry, physics

I am working on a simple 2D game. In the game, I have a 'robot' that throws a ball towards another robot, in the shape of a parabola. Both 'robots' are positioned on the x axis, aka their y co-ordinates are the same.

The program knows the positions of the two robots, and it knows the position of the vertex.

[image]

As I said, I need the ball to travel along the parabola. This means (correct me if I'm wrong), that at any given time, I need to be able to calculate the y position of the ball, since I know it's x position. (Or is there a better way to do this?)

If so, how can I calculate the y position of the ball at any given time, as I said while knowing the location of the parabolas' vertex, and knowing it's two points of intersection with the x axis?

Thanks

EDIT: Please try to make your answers as clear as possible, since my math knowledge is very basic. Thanks

Comment: Since you have those three points, you can fairly easily work out the equation of the parabola (easier to figure it out as if the vertex is at (0, 0) and just shift the final answer), and just plug your `x` into it at any given time. But as it is, this question is more about algebra than programming.

Comment: Hopefully [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+find+equation+of+parabola+given+vertex+and+one+point) will help get you started. But if you still really need help figuring this out, you're more likely to get it at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your parabola is given by `P(x) = a x^2 + b x + c`.  You'll know the formula of the parabola if you know `a`, `b` and `c`.  You have three pieces of information:

```
P(x1) = 0                 (Robot 1 is on the ground at x1)
P(x2) = 0                 (Robot 2 is on the ground at x2)
P((x1 + x2)/2) = yMax     (Half way between the two points the ball is at its maximum)
```

This is three linear equations in three unknowns (you know `x1`, `x2`, `yMax`, you don't know `a`, `b`, `c`). If you know how to solve three equations in three unknowns, you're all set.